# Expressing a Function in Terms of Heaviside Step Functions

Tags: functional-analysis

In my functional analysis class we started working with the Heaviside step function when dealing with Laplace transforms. I can't figure out this one question though

Rewrite the following using Heaviside Step Function:
$
f(t) =
\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } t < 1 \\
    2 & \text{if } 1 \leq t < 2 \\
    -1 & \text{if } 2 \leq t < 3  \\
    0 & \text{if } t \geq 3 \\
\end{cases}
$,
where the Heaviside step function is defined as
$u(t-a) =
\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } t < a \\
    1 & \text{if } t \geq a \\
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn a function $f(t)$ on at time $t=a$ and turn it off at time $t=b$, then use the following form:

$$f(t)(u(t-a) - u(t-b)).$$

The graph of $u(t-a) - u(t-b)$ might be instructive.